# How to get the actual title of a Menu Type object?

Tags: menu, menu-parameters

The SiteMenu Class does not provide any method for getting the menu title column from table *_menu_types.
However that field is editable in the admin section (com_menus section, field 'title').

Is there another way than querying the database to retrieve this field (as encoded in cpanel) ?

If not, does anyone have a sample code with db query ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Just in case it helps anyone, this is how I achieved it:

```
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$active_item = $menu->getActive();

$loader = function ($menu_type) {
    $db = \JFactory::getDbo();
    $result = null;
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select('m.id, m.menutype, m.title, m.description')
        ->where("m.menutype = '{$menu_type}'")
        ->from('#__menu_types AS m');
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $list = $db->loadObjectList();
    if(count($list)) $result = array_shift($list);
    return $result;
};

$menu = $loader($active_item->menutype);
$menu_title = $menu->title;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current menu item alias like so:

```
$alias  = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive()->alias;
```

#### Update:

```
$active = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive();
var_dump($active);
```

or

```
//(int)$id - the actual itemid you want to get;  

$specificMenuItem = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getItem($id);
var_dump($specificMenuItem);
```

See: **[JMenu API](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JMenu.html)**

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong about the table ... updating the question

Comment: @CédricFrançoys : Check answer - $active = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive();
var_dump($active);

Comment: Well thank you, but what I need to achieve is not retrieve the menu item but the menu type to which it belongs, and more precisely the title of that manu type (which, in my case, is 'Main menu')

Comment: @CédricFrançoys - yes I see it now.